# How does this for loop and if statement work?

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out in my own understanding how the for loop and if statement of this function work. This is so because having googled the challenge, this code is shorter but same result as my initial one. The confusion is at the longest variable. It stores the longest lengths of the words greater than str.length(5) - or I may be wrong. For some ununderstood reason, the length of language(8) is not stored in the variable although 5, 10 and 18 are.

```
function longestWord(str) {
    str = str.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            console.log("str = " + str[i]);
            longest = str[i].length;
            console.log("longest = " + longest); //What happended to 8 for language?
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}
console.log(longestWord("Using the JavaScript language bademnostalgiastic"));
```

Comment: `longest` only gets overwritten, if the length of the current “word” is greater than the value already stored in longest. So for `Using` is stores 5, because greater than the current value 0. For `the` it doesn’t do anything, because length 3 is lesser than current value 5. For `JavaScript` is stores 10, for `language` again nothing (because 8 < 10), and then finally it stores 18 for `bademnostalgiastic`.

Comment: That explanation is as clear as it can get. It makes sense now. @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

`JavaScript` is 10 characters long and is tested before `language`, so the `if` test fails and it is skipped.

> It stores the longest lengths of the words greater than str.length(5)

No. It stores the longest length seen so far. It gets `5` when `Using` is tested, but that is quickly overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

All this does it keep track of the longest word (and stores the char count in `longest`).  For each iteration, it tests to see if the next string has more characters than the currently recorded longest string (determined by `longest`).  If it does, it stores the new char count as it is the new "winner of being the longest".

Here's what's happening here:

- take a string and split it up into words (determined by spaces)
- at this point you have a string array of all the individual strings divided by " "
- loop through all of the strings in the array
- if the current string that you are iterating through has character counter more than any other previous ones, then store this current character count in the variable `longest`
- continue the loop and use the above logic in the previous point

So at the end of this all you have the actual string (stored in `word`) and the character count (stored in `longest`) of the word with the most characters.

Comment: In addition to the replies the if statement added to my confusion and was the brick wall to overcoming this bug. the difference is the iterator. This is how I was reading the if statement (longest < str.length) missing out the iterator. Having read the explanations I can see clearly now (longest < str[i].length). @Thomas Stringer

Answer (score 1):

The length of "JavaScript" is 10, which is longer than "language". Since "JavaScript" comes first, "language" won't be longer than the longest, so the if statement will result in false.

Answer (score 1):

`array str[]={Using, the,JavaScript, language ,bademnostalgiastic}`

**Iteration 1**

```
str[i]=Using

str.length=5 (a)

Longest =0   (b)

since (a)>(b)

Longest =5

word=Using
```

**Iteration 2**

```
str[i]=the

str.length=3 (a)

Longest =5   (b)

since (a)<(b)

Longest and word remain same

so,Longest =5

and,word=Using
```

**Iteration 3**

```
str[i]=JavaScript

str.length=10 (a)

Longest =5   (b)

since (a)>(b)



so,Longest =10

and,word=JavaScript
```

**Iteration4**

```
str[i]=language

str.length=8 (a)

Longest =10   (b)

since (a)<(b)
```

so longest remain same

```
so,Longest =10

and,word=JavaScript
```

**Iteration5**

```
str[i]=bademnostalgiastic

str.length=18 (a)

Longest =10   (b)

since (a)>(b)



so,Longest =18

and,word=bademnostalgiastic

END OF LOOP
```

so longest word `bademnostalgiastic`

Comment: Yep the confusion came at the if statment, for that long my brain could not register the iterator in str[i].length. The breakdown is very good explanation @ShekharPankaj

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breakdown:

`str = str.split(" ");`

This is making an array of strings split on spaces.

`for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)`

We're starting here with `i` (the iterator variable) at 0. We're going to keep doing this loop while `i` is less than the length of `str`. We're going to increase `i` by 1 each time we go through this loop.

`if (longest < str[i].length)`

Here we check if the `longest` we've saved is less than the string's length we're looking at.

`longest = str[i].length;`

Here we assign the new longest string, because this one is longer.

`word = str[i];`

We also save the word, likely so we can use it later.

`return word;`

After the loop ends, we're going to send `word` back as the result.

`console.log(longestWord("Using the JavaScript language bademnostalgiastic"));`

This is your call and print statement.

The reason you're seeing 5, 10, and 18, is because you're only printing out values when the value is bigger than what you've already seen.